# Asignar más recursos Python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa para leer PDFs, el problema es que de momento son unos 300+ pdfs que el programa tiene que leer ( Todos están en la misma carpeta ), he lanzado el programa y lee correctamente los pdfs, pero tarda mucho.

Sé que Python por defecto trabaja con un solo proceso y un solo hilo, me gustaría saber como aplicar más hilos a mi programa, dejo el código:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
import os

# Listamos los directorios

listadoDirectorio = os.listdir("../All PDF")

for i in listadoDirectorio:
    text = extract_text("../All PDF/"+i)
    if "BDNS" in text:
        print("El archivo que contiene BDNS es: ",i)
        print("------------------------------------")
```

Gracias un saludo!

Comment: "Mucho" no es un número. Como mínimo deberías publicar un PDF grande y el tiempo que demoras en procesarlo. De ahí podemos partir investigando si se demora "mucho" o poco.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! No se trata de si se tarda mucho o no, lo que me gustaría sabes es como aplicar más hilos a mi programa para reducir ese tiempo "x". Un saludo

Comment: No has establecido una línea de base (cuanto tarda la carga de un PDF, cuanto la búsqueda) ni has medido la ejecución de tu programa. No has determinado la causa del "problema" (I/O, memoria, CPU o tu propio código). La optimización prematura es la raíz de todos los males (Donald Knuth).

Comment: ¿Con qué versión de pdfminer trabajas? La que baje no tiene `extract_text`

Comment: La versión que tengo es "pdfminer.six"

Comment: Ya he comprobado el tiempo que tarda el programa, 18 minutos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127705/discussion-between-candid-moe-and-jorge-rodriguez-mora).